# Copy an image from Windows Phone installation folder to isolated sotorage

Tags: windows-phone-8

Assume that I have an image in my app's installation folder.

e.g. "/Assets/Images/BackgroundImage.jpg"

Any idea how can I save this image to the isolated storage folder?
e.g. "/Shared/ShellContent/BackgroundImage.jpg"

Do I have to use the WriteableBitmap to render it?

I suppose this wouldn't be so hard, however, I'm just so dumb that couldn't figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean by rendering? just displaying or smth more advanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question - how to copy file from Install Folder to Isolated Storage:

```
        var uri = new Uri("Assets\\Images\\BackgroundImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        var sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        var data = sri.Stream;
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile("Shared\\ShellContent\\BackgroundImage.jpg"))
        {
           data.CopyTo(stream);
        }
```

You second question - if you want do display the picture as background:

```
 <Image Source="/Shared/ShellContent/BackgroundImage.jpg" />
```

Of course you need to assign proper properties according to your layout. Also to avoid hardcoding you can bind `Source` to any variable and switch it at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your code looks promising, however, when I try to use `storage.CopyFile`, I got the following exception:
`System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted.`
Do I miss anything?

Comment: No, IsolatedStorage cannot access local folder so exception is Ok - my bad. Fixed and tested sample - it is workaround using `Stream`. Just be sure all directories are created as `CreateFile` throws exceptions otherwise

Comment: Hi Nogard,
When the image is indeed copied to the destination folder, however, the reference to the image doesn't work as expected, when I use this syntax 
`<Image Source="/Shared/ShellContent/BackgroundImage.jpg" />` it only shows a black image instead. Any idea?

Comment: this way it looks up for a picture in installation folder. If you want to get it from Isolated storage you need binding with codebehind or ViewModel (depending on your project structure). Check this snippet: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411 If you need detailed instructions specify how you want to set Image Source

Comment: You are absolutely right! And thanks for the link, the code sample from there worked like a charm!
I would give you a vote when I get enough reputation!